# ORA-00936: missing expression using Entity framework update statement

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm new to using ORACLE with entity framework 5. Trying a simple update statement which won't work and I m getting an error "ORA-00936: missing expression"

```
Entities context = new Entities();

var Description="UpdateTesting";
var Id = "1";

string UpdateSqlString = @"Update SOURCE Set DESCRIPTION={0} where SOURCEID={1}";

int RowsUpdated = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(UpdateSqlString, Description, Id);

context.SaveChanges();
```

I have also tried the following but still getting the same error

```
 Entities context = new Entities();

 var Description = "UpdateTesting";
 var Id = "1";

 var sql = @"Update SOURCE Set DESCRIPTION = @DESCRIPTION WHERE SOURCEID = @Id";

 int RowsUpdated = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new OracleParameter("DESCRIPTION", Description),
                                                                  new OracleParameter("Id", Id));
 context.SaveChanges();
```

I have now tried with the following syntax but nothing happens after the ExecuteSqlCommand and the application probably goes in some not-ending loop

```
var Description="UpdateTesting";
var SOURCEId = "1";

var sql = "Update SOURCE SET DESCRIPTION = :Description WHERE SOURCEID = :SOURCEId";

 int RowsUpdated=context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            sql,
            new OracleParameter(":Description", Description),
            new OracleParameter(":SOURCEId", SOURCEId));
```

I can provide SQL Create table script If that would help resolve this.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: ermm. Tried it but getting this error now "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'."

Comment: Getting slightly different error now "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'"

Comment: Tried with this namespace now "using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;" but now back to the original error "ORA-00936: missing expression"

Comment: Sure. Please see updated

Answer (score 3):

Have you try this?  without colon

```
    var Description="UpdateTesting";
var SOURCEId = "1";

var sql = "Update SOURCE SET DESCRIPTION = :Description WHERE SOURCEID = :SOURCEId";

 int RowsUpdated=context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            sql,
            new OracleParameter("Description", Description),
            new OracleParameter("SOURCEId"   , SOURCEId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `{0}` use `:0` instead.

```
Entities context = new Entities();

var Description="UpdateTesting";
var Id = "1";

string UpdateSqlString = @"Update SOURCE Set DESCRIPTION=:0 where SOURCEID=:1";

int RowsUpdated = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(UpdateSqlString, Description, Id);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add `'` symbol for your update script as the SQL doesn't recognize it as string, like this:

```
Update SOURCE Set DESCRIPTION='{0}' where SOURCEID={1}
```

Try to edit other expressions accordingly.

**Update**:

May be, your problem is in table name (`SOURCE` may be a reserved keyword, and doesn't be recognized as table name) . Try to wrap it in `""`, like this:

```
Update "SOURCE" Set DESCRIPTION='{0}' where SOURCEID={1}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I m getting still the same error after putting `'`

Comment: I have tried the following PL SQL in ORACLE query editor and it works `Update SOURCE 
Set DESCRIPTION='SOme Updates Testing' where SOURCEID=1;`

Comment: In the application, the following line does bring the returns `var Rows = context.SOURCEs.ToList();` so there are no issues in the connection or premissions

Comment: @Learner Did you try the `"` quatation?

Comment: Yes I did but that does not make any difference `string UpdateSqlString = @"Update ""SOURCE"" Set DESCRIPTION={0} where SOURCEID={1}";`